# Would DHCP be considered off topic here?

Tags: discussion

Re: [How DHCP works?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28139/how-dhcp-works)

I feel DHCP is rather on topic for network engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think it should be, but only to a certain degree. Configuring DHCP servers is certainly off-topic, although configuring DHCP in routers has been allowed, but a discussion of how the protocol works probably should be allowed. Based on previous, relatively-recent, DHCP questions which have been marked off-topic by the moderators, this question is off-topic, although I think it would be worth keeping an answering.

I found an [old question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10272/how-does-dhcp-assign-an-ip-address) with the answer to the question you have linked.

Comment: Agreed. The protocol's operation is on topic. Configuration of a DHCP Server (not on a router) is off topic.

Comment: My opinion would be that "Which options do I need for purpose X" is definitely on-topic, including answers and examples in whatever convenient notation including for example Cisco IOS and ISC dhcpd.conf.  "Where do I click? / What file do I edit?" should be off topic.